# SecurityException: Bad package name on Nexus 9

Tags: android

In Android Developer console, inside pre-launch report for Nexus 9 (Android 5.0) the app has crashed with the strange stack trace:

```
09-21 11:58:17.413: E/AbstractServiceBroker(2934): Getting service failed
09-21 11:58:17.413: E/AbstractServiceBroker(2934): java.lang.SecurityException: Bad package name: com.au.ontime
09-21 11:58:17.413: E/AbstractServiceBroker(2934):  at wze.a(:com.google.android.gms:87)
```

And few lines below

```
09-21 11:58:17.558: E/AndroidRuntime(13699): Process: com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 13699
09-21 11:58:17.558: E/AndroidRuntime(13699): java.lang.SecurityException: Bad package name: com.au.ontime
09-21 11:58:17.558: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
09-21 11:58:17.558: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
09-21 11:58:17.558: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at jde.a(:com.google.android.gms:1949)
```

Yes, com.au.ontime is the package name of this application. But why the name of my package is suddenly bad for this device? All other 10 Android devices out of 11 tested run my application fine, and I have never observed such an error on my own Nexus 5 device or any emulator I ever tried.

None of the two stack traces in the log references an execution point inside the actual code of the application. Seems that the application crashed without even starting to run.

The app bundles the sub-app for the wearable watch and has the working code to upload to Google Drive, if this is relevant.